# List the top ten employees from each department

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

How can I list the top ten employees from each department in order and each department the employees should be ordered according to the total amount of purchases?

These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (
    EMPNO NUMBER(4),
    ENAME VARCHAR2(20),
    POSITION VARCHAR2(20),
    DEPTNO NUMBER(2)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPT (
    DEPTNO NUMBER(2),
    DNAME VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE CLIENT (
    CLIENTNO NUMBER(5),
    CNAME VARCHAR2(20),
    PHONE VARCHAR2(10)
);

CREATE TABLE PURCHASE (
    PURCHASENO  NUMBER(5),
    RECEIPTNO   NUMBER(6),
    SERVICETYPE VARCHAR2(25),
    PAYMENTTYPE VARCHAR2(10),
    GST     VARCHAR2(3),
    AMOUNT      NUMBER(4),
    SERVEDBY    NUMBER(4),
    CLIENTNO    NUMBER(5)
);
```

Edited with attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (SELECT E.ENAME, D.DEPTNO, COUNT(P.PURCHASENO) AS TOTALAMOUNT,
             AVG(P.AMOUNT)AS AVGAMOUNT, MAX(P.AMOUNT)AS HIGHESTAMOUNT,
             SUM(P.AMOUNT)AS TOTALAMOUNTPURCHASE,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY DEPTNO ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC)RANK
      FROM EMP E, DEPT D, PURCHASE P
     )
WHERE RANK<=10
```

Comment: `varchar2` suggests Oracle, you might want to add that tag if you are using Oracle.

Comment: but it returned "column ambiguously defined"

Comment: You should always post what you have tried @mattlee because people will be more inclined to help you. You can also edit your own post at any time. Gordon did it for you, but next time edit your post to put the code in there :) I also suggest that you read our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq  Welcome on SO and Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to the problem:

```
 select *
 from (select s.deptno, empno,
              row_number() over (partition by s.deptno order by totamount desc) as seqnum
       from (select servedby, sum(amount) as totamount
             from purchase p
             group by servedby
            ) ps join
            emp e
            on ps.servedby = e.empno
       group by deptno, empno
      ) t
 where seqnum <= 10;
```

Your original query is missing joins between the tables and intermediate levels of aggregation.